# Límite de caracteres en un <A>

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que en un enlace  se limite los carácteres a 30 y cuando sobre pase los 30 caracteres, los demas caracteres se conviertan en `...`

Es decir. Si el título del blog es: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's`

Con lo del límite quiero que quede así: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting...`

```css
        .cont-titles-bn {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1rem 0;
        }
        
        .news-bn {
            padding: 0 1rem;
            width:20%;
            border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .date-bn {
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
```

```html
      <ul class="cont-titles-bn flex">
        <li class="news-bn">
              <p class="date-bn">21:58</p>
              <span class="title-bn">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</span>
          </li>
        <li class="news-bn">
                    <a href="#">
              <p class="date-bn">21:58</p>
              <span class="title-bn">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</span>
                        </a>
          </li>
        <li class="news-bn">
              <p class="date-bn">21:58</p>
              <span class="title-bn">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</span>
          </li>
        <li class="news-bn">
              <p class="date-bn">21:58</p>
              <span class="title-bn">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</span>
          </li>
        <li class="news-bn">
              <p class="date-bn">21:58</p>
              <span class="title-bn">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</span>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: ¿Nos compartes por favor lo que has intentado?

Comment: He intentado encontrar alguna respuesta por los principales foros y web de programación JS pero no he podido encontrar respuesta porque todos trabajan con el campo <input>

Comment: Cualquier avance que tengas será un buen punto de partida para que la comunidad te ayude aún cuando este (tu avance) esté incompleto o incorrecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo mediante js de la siguiente manera:

var text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's"

var newText = text.length > 30 ?  text.substr(0, 30)+'...' : text;

o mediante el uso de css:

```
div {
      width: 230px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/recortar-texto-css-ellipsis.html